# Next steps for playing the piano

Tags: piano, jazz, keyboard, pop-music

I've comfortably played Nuvole Bianche and Fur Elise by watching youtube videos, I can sense patterns between keys and I think have developed some musical sense(I can pick up new song, only with the right hand though). Besides this I have no knowledge of musical theory and have no formal education in music. Can anyone please guide me for my next steps- I like Jazz, and some composed version of popular pop songs, not a big fan of classical music. But if there are some techniques that are transferable then I'm ready to learn anything.

Sorry for rambling, please would love some advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me as a bit strange that you don't like classical style, but learned *Fur Elise*. Then again, I don't like that piece, but learned it, because it's a common student assignment.

I would encourage learning classical music for two reasons: so much of piano technique comes from playing classical repertoire, and a lot of jazz players were also very good classical players. Try to think of *not* as an either/or choice. Maybe think of classical style as a sort of neutral foundation in keyboard technique that you can branch out of.

You don't need approach classical style as if your goal is becoming a concern pianist playing Rachmaninoff and Liszt. There is tons and tons of material of easy to moderate difficulty, for example:

- Czerny, Recreations
- Clementi, Art of Piano Playing
- Schubert, various sets of dances, lots of them are waltzes

All that stuff and more is available at https://imslp.org/

There is some music that tries to bridge classical and jazz, like Oscar Peterson's *Jazz Etudes*.

If classical style doesn't interest you, because the harmony style is too bland, especially the case with some of the easy stuff, you could try other time periods. The Renaissance period offer lots of keyboard books with amateur level material, examples *Fitzwilliam Virginal Book* or *Musick's Handmaid*. On the other end is early 20th century stuff like Bartok's *Mikrokosmos*, a large collection of graded piano music with interesting modern harmonies and rhythms.

Maybe all of this isn't your cup of tea. I'm telling you about stuff I have in my own music collection. Perhaps you want more pop style stuff. That's fine. But, you might consider exposing yourself to some of the material I'm suggesting. It's all *original* keyboard music and will provide transferrable skills. The classical stuff - including musical eras before and after - should be especially good for developing technical skills.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Not complete Fur Elise- the first part, which most beginners play. And besides playing good piano, one immediate interest of mine is doing my own covers of pop songs; can you suggest how do I learn this skill? Will this come automatically after I get some more experience? @Michael Curtis

Comment: "my own covers..." you might try search for things like "how to play from a lead sheet." The things I have seen are mostly about how to ad lib the accompaniment in the left hand while reading the melody from a lead sheet with chord symbols.

Comment: Oh, another that you might look up is "Book of a Thousand Songs" at imslp.org. It's all old time songs. The accompaniment styles are pretty consistent from song to song, mostly rolling chord arpeggios, bass/chord, and block chord. All of that is very common, but it's helpful to see the application in hundreds of songs. All compact for reading too, just one or two songs per page on average.

Comment: If playing "pop", means to you just the most recent songs, like Taylor Swift, etc. the challenge will probably be less _how to play_, but how to get the lead sheets, or without notated music, how to first figure out the tune by ear. Each of which are very different challenges.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please guide me for my next steps

Far and and away your best option is to start taking lessons. A flesh and blood teacher will be able to guide you far better than this forum and that route is the way to the fastest improvement and the greatest enjoyment.